# TableViewController populates on search, but won't load initial view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

*Swift 5, iOS 12, Xcode 10*

I finally implemented a search bar on my **ListingsViewController** and it's working really well -- but the initial data isn't populating into the table.

I realize that this is a clumsy implementation, but I'm learning as I go and I'm using only code that I can understand. I've been at this for two days -- I've tried creating a **Struct** and bringing in the data that way, but I can't even get an **Array**. I've tried bringing it in as an **NSArray** and an **Array** and an **Object**, but either I can't get the initial table to load, or I can't get data to parse out at all, or I can't get the search to work.

I suspect it has something to do with how, when or where I'm calling the **loadData()** function but I just can't figure it out.

```
class ListingsViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating { 
    var tableData = [String]()
    var filteredTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (tableData as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        tableData = [String]()
        loadData()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
        resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "--------------") else {return  }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return
            }
            do {
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
                for dic in jsonArray {
                    self.tableData.append(dic["name"] as! String)
                    //                    self.feedItems.append(Listing(id: (dic["id"] as! String), city_id: (dic["city_id"] as! String), category: (dic["category"] as! String), sub_category: (dic["sub_category"] as! String), name: (dic["name"] as! String), phone: (dic["phone"] as! String), email: (dic["email"] as! String), website: (dic["website"] as! String), address: (dic["address"] as! String), comment: (dic["comment"] as! String), recommendedby: (dic["recommendedby"] as! String)))
                }
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        task.resume()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (resultSearchController.isActive) {
            return filteredTableData.count
        } else {
            return tableData.count
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.backgroundColor = .black
        cell.tintColor = .lightText
        if (resultSearchController.isActive) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the entire list of Listings to appear when I switch to the **ListingsViewController** from the tab bar. Instead, I get a blank table.

HOWEVER, If I tap into the search bar and start typing, though, I get matching results -- and when I cancel the search, I can see all of the results in the table.

(Also, when I tap into the search bar, my navigation bar goes away and doesn't come back, even when I cancel the search. Even if I switch to a different tab and come back. Haven't been able to figure that one out.)

Comment: Have you set the data source and delegate to the tableView

Comment: @kjoe Yes, thank you -- I set them in the Storyboard. I've also tried them in the code, in the `viewDidAppear` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your load day to this

```
func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "--------------") else’s  {return  }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return
            }
            do {
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
                for dic in jsonArray {
                    self.tableData.append(dic[“name”] as! String
                }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("call to reload data")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

your are callig to reload data before the completion block, you can check it with the following `print("calling to reloadData")` then test my solution and see that works, make a print statamente for `JsonArray` to check where is called, you must reload the tableViewData after the async func is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the delegate and data source for the table view
add this:

```
class ListingsViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
//your class code here
}
```

and on your `viewDidLoad`  add this:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

that should work, Please notice that after you called the delegate and data source your cell for row and numbers of rows functions will be called so make sure the array you are using is not nil by then

Comment: Thank you, but that's throwing two errors I expected to get: `Redundant conformance of 'ListingsViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'` and `Redundant conformance of 'ListingsViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'`. This is a `UITableViewController` so if I declare it as the `dataSource` and `delegate`it fails.

Comment: I added those two lines in the `viewDidLoad()` after the `loadData()` call, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @JoshGoldwasser you have conformance to the protocol, press on the red error and let Xcode complete the protocol, you need to add cell for row and number of rows in sections methods.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you haven't been missing delegate and data source for the table view.
You must register delegate and data source for viewcontroler. where you will display data.

Please insert this code on your viewDidLoad

self.tableView.delegate = self

self.tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: Hi, thank you — but that didn't work. Adding those two lines didn't change anything at all.